# LLDB analog for GDB "info sym"

Tags: c++, debugging, lldb

Is there an analog command in LLDB to show current binary file where the symbol is located? In GDB it can be done with `info sym` command, like shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67707616/9363996) answer.

This is crucial for ODR violation checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://lldb.llvm.org/use/symbolication.html#id3 has a command just for that:
`image lookup --address 0x100123aa3 --verbose`
The info about a file is shown even without `--verbose` option.

Comment: BTW, if you do this a bunch, the shortest typed version is: `im loo -va <ADDR>`