# How to find name of a shared object that contains given function in GDB?

Tags: gdb, shared-libraries, backtrace

In GDB, I can observe which source code file names and line numbers are associated with current execution state, other positions in current backtrace, and in many other contexts (such as breakpoints). But if I require to learn from which shared object (*.so, *.dll, or other type of image) a given line of code comes, how do I learn that?

The reason why it is important: suppose I am debugging a complex application that dynamically loads many shared objects. In a backtrace output, I see that execution passes a position in source code which I am not familiar with. I want to rebuild the encompassing shared library with debug information preserved to simplify my next debugging session. But in order to do this, I need to know the name of the library. I only know the name of a source file that was used to build it, because it is shown in the debugger output. How to I proceed in a most straightforward way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GDB show current compiled binary file for function address on call stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699542/gdb-show-current-compiled-binary-file-for-function-address-on-call-stack) (the `info symbol` command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to rebuild the encompassing shared library with debug information preserved to simplify my next debugging session.

Generally this is the wrong approach. Instead you should build *everything* with debug info, and use `strip` before shipping the result to the end-user (but keep unstripped version for subsequent debugging).

> I see that execution passes a position in source code which I am not familiar with.

Use `up` to get to that level, and `info symbol $pc` to find out where that symbol came from. Example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc > 0) abort();
  return 0;
}

gcc -g t.c

gdb -q ./a.out

(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
50      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) info sym $pc
raise + 321 in section .text of /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) up
#1  0x00007ffff7e04537 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
79      abort.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) info sym $pc
abort + 291 in section .text of /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) up
#2  0x000055555555514f in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdb88) at t.c:3
3         if (argc > 0) abort();
(gdb) info sym $pc
main + 26 in section .text of /tmp/a.out
```

You could also just use address explicitly without stepping into the function:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
50      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
#1  0x00007ffff7e04537 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x000055555555514f in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdb88) at t.c:3
(gdb) info sym 0x00007ffff7e04537
abort + 291 in section .text of /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) info sym 0x000055555555514f
main + 26 in section .text of /tmp/a.out
```